# substring on Non Asci charater in java and Scala

Tags: java, string, scala, substring

I am not able to find a method in java or scala to do a substring on non-ascii character using the absolute length from getBytes

```
 val string = "achâth33Franklin"

string.length
 Int = 16

string.getBytes.length
 Int = 17

 string.substring(0,7)
String = achâth3
```

I need a method that results in **achâth** as it has non-ascii character whose length is 2

```
 val test = "â"
test.getBytes.length
res26: Int = 2
```

To give more perspective on the problem.

The length of the field is constant which is 7, it always will be ascii value. Some times, they send non ascii value in the string. 
The result substring(0,7), when they non-ascii values moving the next field values into current value.

Explination for @VGR

```
scala> val string = "achâth33Franklin"
string: String = achâth33Franklin

scala> new String(string.getBytes,0,7)
res30: String = achâth

scala> string.substring(0,7)
res31: String = achâth3
```

Comment: Why are you using `getBytes` at all?  If you want a substring, use character indexes, not byte indexes.

Comment: @VGR The length of the field is constant which is 7, it always will be ascii value. Some times, they send non ascii value in the file. When we do substring(0,7). Then the next field is moving into name field

Comment: All the more reason *not* to use bytes.  Using characters, ASCII and non-ASCII are treated exactly the same.

Comment: @VGR agreed, Main concern is length of the string is wrong when we treating them as charaters.  Explanation provided at last in the question

Comment: Why you can't read 7 bytes from file with offset? Or first read to byte array or stream?
Note: Google Guava has fast `encodedLength` method for UTF-8.

Comment: If you want the string `"achâth"`, you want the first six characters, so why not just write `string.substring(0, 6)`?

Comment: "always will be ascii value. Some times, they send non ascii value in the file": Then send it back as invalid! Or, sometjhing isn't right with your explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to combine the [`getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) method with [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int)).

So your method would look like this:

```
String string = "achâth33Franklin";
string.substring(0,7); //achâth3
new String(string.getBytes(), 0, 7)); //achâth
```

That constructor takes an array of bytes, an offset into the array, and the number of bytes to use. so `new String(string.getBytes(), a, b)` works with the same logic as `string.substring(a, b)`, but per-byte instead of per-character.

Comment: I am processing a large file, afraid of creating many objects.